# I'm using backgroundworker and getting: InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid - how should I handle it?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

Consider:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap newbmp = new Bitmap(512, 512);
    IEnumerable<Point> CommonList = null;
    StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\diff\diff.txt");
    pixelscoordinatesinrectangle = new List<Point>();
    pixelscoordinatesinrectangle = pointsAffected.ToList();
    DrawIt = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < trackBar1FileInfo.Length; i++)
    {
        DrawIt = true;
        this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            trackBar1.Value = i;

                    LoadPictureAt(trackBar1.Value, sender);
                    pictureBox1.Load(trackBar1FileInfo[i].FullName);

            ConvertedBmp = ConvertTo24(trackBar1FileInfo[trackBar1.Value].FullName);
            ConvertedBmp.Save(ConvertedBmpDir + "\\ConvertedBmp.bmp");
            mymem = ToStream(ConvertedBmp, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        }));
        Button1Code();
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
        newpixelscoordinates = new List<Point>();
        newpixelscoordinates = pointsAffected.ToList();
        CommonList = pixelscoordinatesinrectangle.Intersect(newpixelscoordinates);
        foreach (Point s in CommonList)
        {
            w.WriteLine("The following points are the same" + s);
            newbmp.SetPixel(s.X, s.Y, Color.Red);
        }
    }
    w.Close();
    using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(newbmp))
    {
        G.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }
    newbmp.Save(@"c:\newbmp\newbmp.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
    newbmp.Dispose();
}
```

Exception message:

> Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'pictureBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

I tried to use `this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate`

Even now when using the code after the BeginInvoke, it is showing the exception so I need to use the BeginInvoke on the other code too.

Is using BeginInvoke a good way? Or I should solve it in other way and if so how?

Comment: you are accessing picturebox from **outside of** the BeginInvoke delegate : `pictureBox1.Refresh();`

Comment: Ok now all the code in the DoWork in the BeginInvoke and it's working the problem is that the loop over trackBar1FileInfo still freezing my program while doing it. I'm using backgroundworker and still it's freezing my program untill it finish. trackBar1FileInfo contain like 5000 files to loop over. Why it's still freezing my program while working if it's inside a backgroundworker ?

Comment: It's likely that you could (and should) refactor this so that you are using the new `async` model (e.g. `Task.Run()`, `Progress<T>` class). But if you want to continue using the `BackgroundWorker`, pay close attention to the advice kennyzx has provided in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows GUI programming:

1. Move the time-consuming task to a separate thread to keep UI responsive, you choose to use BackgroundWorker, that is a good choice.
2. You can't access UI elements from background thread (the `Cross-thread operation not valid` exception), that is why you need to call `BeginInvoke` to access the Picturebox.

Remember the code called by `BeginInvoke` is actually running on UI thread. So if you put *all the code in the DoWork in BeginInvoke*, it is the same as not using `Backgroundworker`- actually it is even worse, because creating a new thread and marshaling the call to UI thread have significant performance overhead.

So you should call `BeginInvoke` only when it is necessary - when the code needs to access UI elements, the rest code should not be wrapped inside `BeginInvoke`.